# Prevent Command Line Usage During Function Run in Python/Terminal?

Tags: python

I'm using Terminal to run a python script with a series of print statements, separated by the time.sleep function.

If I'm printing various items over a period of 10 seconds, I would like to be able to prevent the user from inputting new commands into the command line during this time.

Is this possible in Terminal?  Is there a work-around?

---

---

My goal here is to be able to provide the user with a lot of print statements, then have them answer a question *only after the question is asked*.

Because I don't want to overwhelm the user, I want to time delay the print statements so it appears more manageable (well, it's really for theatrical effect).

ie

```
for i in range(10):
    print "Eating cheeseburger..."
    time.sleep(1)

response = raw_input("What is your favorite color?")
if response == "blue":
    blah blah blah etc.
```

Right now, the user can input a response before the question is asked, and while the cheeseburger is still being eaten.  I want to prevent this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is a platform specific one, as different operating systems handle standard input and output differently. I will attempt to answer your question for Linux:

You can use `os.system` to access the linux command `stty -echo` to make any text entered on the terminal invisible, and `stty echo` to make it visible again.

The next thing you want to achieve is to clear the stdin buffer when user input is asked. This can be achieved through the `termios` function `tcflush` that can be used to flush all input that has been received but not read by the terminal yet.

```
import os
import time
import termios
import sys

os.system("stty -echo")
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
    time.sleep(1)
os.system("stty echo")

termios.tcflush(sys.stdin, termios.TCIOFLUSH)

print(raw_input("Answer now:"))
```

Comment: Yeah, this appears to be exactly what I wanted! But, I think your description is not technically completely correct.  Not only does this command appear to flush user input before user input is requested, but it ALSO appears to prevent user input before this time altogether.

ie with a flushing right before user input is requested, I should still be able to trigger the "if response == "blue":" statement if I can give the user input "blue" before that user input is flushed.

Comment: @ColinHancey, `tcflush` discards data that hasn't been read or transmitted. Without it, anything typed up to that point will be read by `raw_input`. I added a call to `FlushConsoleInputBuffer` for the same reason in my Windows version of this answer.

Comment: I gave the tcflush description directly from [link](https://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/sasc/doc/lr2/tcflush.htm), don't think its inaccurate.

Comment: The description at the link says it is used "to flush all input that has received but not yet been read by a terminal," but it also appears to keep the terminal from reading the input.  Please try both of our codes and observe that you could trigger the "if" statement in mine before the print statements are finished.  Yours (thankfully) prevents this.  I believe that this constant prevention is different from a one-time flush right after the print statements are finished.

Comment: From what I understand, in your code the if statement gets triggered before the print statements are finished? This is because raw_input reads from stdin till it encounters a `\n` which is given when you hit enter. But when you flush the stdin, it removes everything entered thus far including any `\n`, which is why my solution appears to prevent what you say?

Comment: Oh, that's interesting.  So it is indeed a one-time flush, but it is able to flush any user input submitted already with the RETURN key, if I understand correctly.  So then my understanding is that the raw_input does not receive the user input until after the print statements are finished, and it includes every instance of the user pressing RETURN.  Just after the print statements finish, all user input is submitted at once, so a one-time flush is all that is needed to clear all inputs, including each time the RETURN key was pressed.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a version of [Saurabh Shirodkar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43691582/205580) written for the Windows console using ctypes.

```
import sys
import msvcrt
import ctypes

kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)

ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT = 0x0004

def _check_bool(result, func, args):
    if not result:
        raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())
    return args

kernel32.GetConsoleMode.errcheck = _check_bool
kernel32.GetConsoleMode.argtypes = (ctypes.c_void_p,
    ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ulong))
kernel32.SetConsoleMode.errcheck = _check_bool
kernel32.SetConsoleMode.argtypes = (ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_ulong)
kernel32.FlushConsoleInputBuffer.errcheck = _check_bool
kernel32.FlushConsoleInputBuffer.argtypes = (ctypes.c_void_p,)

def echo_input(enable=True, conin=sys.stdin):
    h = msvcrt.get_osfhandle(conin.fileno())
    mode = ctypes.c_ulong()
    kernel32.GetConsoleMode(h, ctypes.byref(mode))
    if enable:
        mode.value |= ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT
    else:
        mode.value &= ~ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT
    kernel32.SetConsoleMode(h, mode)

def flush_input(conin=sys.stdin):
    h = msvcrt.get_osfhandle(conin.fileno())
    kernel32.FlushConsoleInputBuffer(h)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time

    if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
        input = raw_input

    echo_input(False)

    for i in range(10):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(1)

    echo_input(True)
    flush_input()

    print(input("Answer now: "))
```